# npm install only fails when used with child_process.exec

Tags: node.js, npm, child-process

Running this in my terminal:
`npm i --save-dev typescript 'https://gitpkg.now.sh/pylonbot/pylon-sdk-types/runtime' 'https://gitpkg.now.sh/pylonbot/pylon-sdk-types/runtime-discord'` 
Installs the packages as would be expected. But, when I try to use child_process's execSync to install these packages the installation fails.
The code:

```js
try {
  child_process.execSync(`npm i --save-dev typescript 'https://gitpkg.now.sh/pylonbot/pylon-sdk-types/runtime' 'https://gitpkg.now.sh/pylonbot/pylon-sdk-types/runtime-discord'`);
} catch(e) {
  console.log(e);
  process.exit();
} finally {
  console.log('It worked!');
}
```

Output:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\me\test\'https:\gitpkg.now.sh\pylonbot\pylon-sdk-types\runtime'/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\me\test\'https:\gitpkg.now.sh\pylonbot\pylon-sdk-types\runtime'\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

Interestingly, it only fails when the gitpkgs are included (gitpkg is a tool that lets you install packages from github subdirs) 
Sorry in advance if this is something stupid, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason, removing the quotes around the gitpkg link fixed this.